# How can I configure Apache to map /talk.html?id=77 to the file that is called talk.html?id=77?

Tags: apache, apache-config

I have a web application of a conference that has been closed years ago. There is no real need for the application to be running any more so I'd like to create static pages from the dynamically generated pages.

I ran    wget http://site.name.org/  and now I have bunch of files called talk.html?id=77 with numbers from 1-300

How can I configure Apache to map the request of /talk.html?id=77 to the actual file that is called talk.html?id=77 ?

(Using Apache 2.2 )

Comment: How can you have files with a "?" in the name?

Comment: DR: It is possible, on Unixes at least. I don't know about Windows.

Comment: Haha, the windows guys are confused :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do any special configuration to Apache.

However, when requesting the file, you need to encode the `?` in the URL so that it is not interpreted as a querystring.

The URL encoding of `?` is `%3F`.

So the URL that should work for that file is `/talk.html%3Fid=77`

Comment: Interesting solving the problem from the other direction :-) The problem is that now I see the source of these files. I guess Apache is serving them with "text" mime-type instead of "html" mime-type. So I have to configure that now. (Though actually this will also break any link from outside of this site)

Comment: DefaultType text/html

in the VirtualHost